# Poor performance of base_local_planner - advice for parameter tuning?

Tags: ros, navigation, parameters, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am having some issues with object avoidance when using move_base. As you can see in [this video I made](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nf28qb-ZhEc&feature=youtu.be) the robot doesn't navigate the obstacles in a smooth manner. My suspicion is that my local_planner parameters need tuning. However I've spend hours playing with all the different parameters and am not seeing improved results.
I have checked my odometry data and it's very accurate, so that's not the problem.

I'll attach my parameter configuration files below. I would really appreciate any tips, particularly from those who have success in tuning their robots to navigate smoothly around obstacles.

---

**base_local_planner_params.yaml**

```
controller_frequency: 2.0
recovery_behavior_enabled: false
clearing_rotation_allowed: false

TrajectoryPlannerROS:
   max_vel_x: 0.36
   min_vel_x: 0.2
   max_vel_y: 0.0  # zero for a differential drive robot
   min_vel_y: 0.0
   max_vel_theta: 0.7
   min_vel_theta: -0.7
   min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.5
   escape_vel: -0.15
   acc_lim_x: 0.3 # From test trials (0.304,0.285,0.26,0.365)
   acc_lim_y: 0.0 # zero for a differential drive robot
   acc_lim_theta: 1.0 #probably closer to 1.3 

   holonomic_robot: false
   yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25 # about 12 degrees
   xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25  # 20 cm
   latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false
   pdist_scale: 0.6
   gdist_scale: 0.7
   meter_scoring: true

   heading_lookahead: 0.375

   heading_scoring: false
   heading_scoring_timestep: 0.8
   occdist_scale: 0.01
   oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05
   publish_cost_grid_pc: false
   prune_plan: true

   #sim_time: 4
   sim_granularity: 0.025
   angular_sim_granularity: 0.025
   vx_samples: 8
   vy_samples: 0 # zero for a differential drive robot
   vtheta_samples: 20
   dwa: true
   simple_attractor: false
```

**costmap_common_params.yaml**

```
obstacle_range: 4.0
raytrace_range: 5.0
inf_is_valid: false
robot_radius: 0.3 # - dont need a radius if we have a footprint.
inflation_radius: 0.3
# footprint: [[-15,0.26],[0.42,0.26],[0.42,-0.26],[-15,-0.26]] # Note Base_link is on top of the lidar and x axis is forwards


observation_sources: scan
scan:
  data_type: LaserScan
  topic: scan
  marking: true
  clearing: true    

map_type: costmap
```

**global_costmap_params.yaml**

```
global_costmap:
   global_frame: /map
   robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
   update_frequency: 1.0
   publish_frequency: 0.5
   static_map: true
   rolling_window: false
   resolution: 0.025
   transform_tolerance: 1.0
   map_type: costmap
```

**local_costmap_params.yaml**

```
local_costmap:
   global_frame: /odom
   robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
   update_frequency: 1
   publish_frequency: 2
   static_map: false
   rolling_window: true
   width: 5.0
   height: 5.0
   resolution: 0.025
   transform_tolerance: 1.0
   map_type: costmap
```

**move_base_params.yaml**

```
shutdown_costmaps: false

controller_frequency: 5.0 #before 5.0
controller_patience: 3.0


planner_frequency: 0.5
planner_patience: 5.0

oscillation_timeout: 10.0
oscillation_distance: 0.2

conservative_reset_dist: 0.10 #distance from an obstacle at which it will unstuck itself
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261625/poor-performance-of-base_local_planner---advice-for-parameter-tuning?/) by [mcarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/30108/mcarr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2017-05-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-05-13**:
Suggestion: Check your cmd_vel accuracy. Real world/odom reported translation and rotation should match the cmd_vel input.

**Comment by [mcarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/30108/mcarr/) on 2017-05-15**:
Thanks Humpels, I used rqt_plot to view /odom and /cmd_vel and saw some differences so tuned my PID parameters now the velocities match better. However the problem still exists. I also increased sim_time to help avoid the obstacles earlier but this made it perform even worse. Any other tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

The problem was that I was using **TrajectoryPlannerROS instead of DWALocalPlannerROS**. I changed the heading TrajectoryPlannerROS to DWALocalPlannerROS in base_local_planner_params.yaml and added

```
base_local_planner: dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS
```

to my move_base_params.yaml.

This completely changed the behaviour of the robot. Now it's avoiding obstacles very smoothly and not having the strange problems as before. Although I think my footprint and inflation radius still needs some optimising, it's working much better!

---

Originally posted by [mcarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/30108/mcarr/) with karma: 145 on 2017-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mcarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/30108/mcarr/) on 2017-05-18**:
If anyone is struggling with poor move_base behaviour, I strongly recommend you to visualize the **Trajectory Cloud** in rviz. This is possible with dwa_local_planner by adding the line `publish_traj_pc: true` to the config file `base_local_planner_params.yaml`. Then use dynamic reconfigure to tune

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2017-11-22**:
Hi,

I am struggling with the `DWA_local_planner`, it is strange that it detects obstacles and completely stops. could you look at   [my question](https://answers.ros.org/question/276472/dwa-local-planner-fails-to-produce-path/)  and share with me your experience?

Thanks in advance,